# Aliens collect butterflies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Multidimensional aliens start collecting butterflies in bubbles. Nothing can stop them and the Earth is then destroyed. It was a short story. I remember the aliens were like robots, with spooky smiling faces that were only vaguely human.

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86783/looking-for-a-story-about-the-end-of-life-on-earth

Comment: I tried to follow link and could not find the reference.

Comment: Never mind. That's the correct story.